# How to assign multiple keys to one keyboard shortcut?

Tags: anki

I have the "Customize Keyboard Shortcuts" Add-on already installed on Anki.

I want to assign multiple keyboard shortcuts for the same command ("Undo")

I've tried this, But it didn't work :

"m_toolbox undo": {

"m_toolbox undo+++ 1st": "d",
.
"m_toolbox undo+++ 2nd": "u",

},

Please help! Thanks in advance!